# taxid2wgs.pl: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_handshake

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, centos7, ncbi

I trying to run a Perl script ([taxid2wgs.pl](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/WGS_TOOLS/README_BLASTWGS.txt)) used in searching a taxonomic subset of WGS.

taxid2wgs.pl (available at ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/WGS_TOOLS).

```
$ ./taxid2wgs.pl -title "Bacteria WGS" -alias_file bacteria-wgs 2
```

Here, `2` is the taxid for Bacteria. `taxid2wgs.pl` will produce the alias file "**bacteria-wgs.nvl**".

However I got an error message below.

```
Can't locate LWP/UserAgent.pm in @INC (you may need to install the LWP::UserAgent module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.0 .) at ./taxid2wgs.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./taxid2wgs.pl line 4.
```

What I do next is install the LWP perl module ([libwww-perl-6.05](http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/LWP/libwww-perl-6.05.tar.gz)).

```
~# perl Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
perl: symbol lookup error: /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/List/Util/Util.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_handshake
```

Before posting, I've tried to another solution.

```
~# perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::LWP'
perl: symbol lookup error: /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/List/Util/Util.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_handshake
```

To overcome the problem, I used YUM to install the required module named **perl-libwww-perl**.

```
~# yum install perl-libwww-perl
```

But it still doesn't work for my operation.

Sorry, I'm very new to this. Appreciate the help!

Comment: maybe you can try yum install perl-Scalar-List-Utils to fix that. otherwise you can try cpan List::Util to fix that?

Comment: This usually indicates you are using a library that was compiled for a different `perl` than the one you are using.

Comment: A big thank you, I see my problem now! The following worked for me: I check `locate UserAgent.pm` and `export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl5/`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. And like others have said, this is because the program uses a different perl. I got the error when I used perl 5.24.0, but the program worked with perl-5.18.2.

Comment: If you had the same issue that others have addressed already then there's no need to post a new answer.